# Reference data using surrounding elements

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize, watir, browser-automation

I'd like to extract a set of numbers from a list. The list items are identified by headings within them, and appear in a random order. I'd like to assign (in the first list item, for example) the number (`1,287,498`) to the heading contained in the same `<li>` tag (`Russia`).

```
<ul>

<li> 
<h6>Russia</h6> 
<p>Red</p> 
<p>1,287,498</p>
</li>

<li> 
<h6>USA</h6> 
<p>Blue</p>
<p>782,2378,223</p>
</li>

...etc.

</ul>
```

I want something like this:

```
russia = 1,287,498
```

I tried using XPath, but it didn't work, presumably because the order is random; it kept assigning wrong variables.

Comment: So how are you using XPath? Are you getting all of the `<li>` elements? and processing that or something else? What is random? Is the order of the `<li>` elements random, or the order of the elements within the `<li>` ?

Comment: Sorry for my lack of clarity, I meant to say that the order of the `<li>` elements is random.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lis = doc.xpath('//li') # Or however you are getting the right elements

data = Hash[ lis.map{ |li| [li.at('h6').text, li.search('p').last.text] }]
#=> {
#=>   "Russia" => "1,287,498",
#=>   "USA"    => "782,2378,223",
#=> }

p data["Russia"]
#=> "1,287,498"
```

This answer assumes that the `<p>` with the number is the last paragraph in the `<li>`. It's hard to know if this is correct as you have not shared a full document.

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was unaware that you could simply use `last.text`.

Comment: @N1ghtshade3 Aye, `Node#search`, `Node#css`, and `Node#xpath` all return a [`NodeSet`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html), which is very much like an Array.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using the CSS sibling selectors `~` or `+`:

```
doc.at('h6[text()=Russia] ~ p:last').text
#=> "1,287,498"
doc.at('h6[text()=Russia] + p + p').text
#=> "1,287,498"
```